# PHP Tree/matrix find first free node below a set of nodes

Tags: php, mysql, matrix, tree

I have a MySql table representation of my tree/matrix like this

idposition (int,AI)

iduser (int) //the user the position belongs to

parentposition (int) //the id of the parent

ordering (tinyint) //from 1 to 3 to identify the ordering below the parent position

status (tinyint) //from 0 to 3 to indentify how many child the node has

I need to fill the tree from top to bottom, left to right.
A node can have a max of 3 child.
In case a new position must be inserted then the position must be under a specified user in the "higher" possibile level in the tree.
A user can have more than one position so I need to get the "higher available position below a specific user".

Can you please help me in do this in MySQL/PHP?

since now i'm here

```
$idmatrixposition=calculated and found the first position of the user.
$idparentposition=getAvailableMatrixPosition($idmatrixposition , $matrixtype);
function getAvailableMatrixPosition($matrixposition =NULL, $matrixtype)
{
    global $link;
    echo "<BR>gAMP:: $matrixposition<BR>";
    if ($matrixposition == NULL ) {
        echo "MATRIXPOSITION NULL";
        return array();
    }
    $query = "select * from matrixpositions where idposition=$matrixposition";
    $result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $total = $row['status'];

    echo "<BR>MatrixPosition ID $matrixposition has $total positions below:: ". ($total >= 3 ? " FULL. " : " Available :)") ."<BR>";

    if ($total < 3){
        echo "<BR>OK: $matrixposition - $total";
        return $matrixposition;
    } else {
        $query = "select * from matrixpositions where parentposition=$matrixposition order by ordering asc";
        $result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
        $i=0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $i++;
            if ($i==1) $firstchild=$row['idposition'];
            $total = $row['status'];
            $childmatrixposition=$row['idposition'];
            if ($total < 3){
                echo "<BR>OK Child: $childmatrixposition - $total - ".$row['ordering'];
                return $childmatrixposition;
            } else {
                echo "<BR>KO Child: $childmatrixposition - $total - ".$row['ordering'];
            }
        }
        if ($i==3) {
            echo "<BR>KO FirstChild: $firstchild";
            $position=getAvailableMatrixPosition($firstchild, $matrixtype);
            return $position;
        }
    } 
}
```

It works with only one position for user.
How can I extend it to find the best position under multiple positions of the same user?
Thanks